# Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

when I click on "login with facebook" it gives this error "Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function".
user has logged in but my app not showing home page. When I login without facebook its working correctly

login error screenshot http://prntscr.com/ezge48

```
    export function LoginWithFacebook(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){
            var user = result.user;
            console.log("LoginSuccess");
            dispatch(AllActions.userSignInSuccess(user))
            browserHistory.replace('/home')
        })
                .catch((error) => {
                console.log("login error", error)
                dispatch(AllActions.userSignInFailed(error))
            })
    }
}
```

below body of HTML

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : ' app id here ',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: can you show the error stack ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ezge48

Comment: Looks like it's coming from their SDK? do you have the latest version?

Comment: Yes I have latest SDK

Comment: I am not using React but I had the same issue. I realized that I haven't added onlogin event to the button. The error has gone.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same error yesterday, we can see at the line 156:

```
    var s=i.getVal(r,'on_login'),
        t=null,
        u=this._iframeOptions.name;

    if(s)
    {
        t=function v(w)
        {
            if(w.error_code)
            {
                j.debug('Plugin Return Error (%s): %s',w.error_code,w.error_message||w.error_description);
                return;
            }
            h.invokeHandler(s,null,[w]);
        };
        this.subscribe('login.status',t);
    }
```

So if you don't have a valide onlogin attribute on your div class="fb-login-button" this t function is not declared, if I try simply with:

```
<div
    class="fb-login-button"
    data-max-rows="1"
    data-size="large"
    data-button-type="login_with"
    data-show-faces="false"
    data-use-continue-as="true"
    data-scope="email"
    onlogin="console.log('connected')"
></div>
```

I don't have this problem, all is right.